# Subscribe to an Event Grid Domain Topic using WebHook from a different directory/organization

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an Event Domain in exampleA.onmicrosoft.com (Domain A). All applications are in Domain A can subscribe to topics from Event Domain.

I have then have another organization/domain: exampleB.onmicrosoft.com (Domain B). I want an application to subscribe to topics from Domain A.

Is is possible?

I have tried to add a new subscriber to a topic, but I keep getting an error with the Webhook validation handshake, even though I have added code to resolve the handshake (similar to applications from Domain A).

Can anyone help?

[Screenshot of Deploying Event Subscription error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk3Ga.png)

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458963/send-azure-blob-storage-event-notifications-to-event-hubs-on-another-account

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add answers to your questions. I have rolled back/edited your question. Please write a new answer instead.

Comment: Hi, I have post the answer for you to close this question.